# Selenium 3.0.1 is showing Marionette driver as Obsolete !!! Anyone knows anything about it?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

[snapshot of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFSZc.png)
Selenium 3.0.1 is showing Marionette driver as Obsolete. Anyone knows anything about it?

[image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2kK0Mk0C_6UeHl0b0dfUFItRW8][1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as of Selenium 3 this class has been deprecated. You should use `FirefoxDriver` instead. [Here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/FirefoxTest.java) you can see a JUnit example.